# Odd Internet Explorer 7 bug; not calculating padding on links correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

It would appear that I am suffering from a new bug in IE7, as I can't seem to find any reference to it anywhere else. It is best explained using screenshots, so here are a couple of links (and as a note, it's not a requirement for it to work in IE6, so I don't even want to know what it looks like under that!):

How it should be displayed (using Safari 4):
http://dl-client.getdropbox.com/u/45961/safari4.png

How IE7 is displaying it:
http://dl-client.getdropbox.com/u/45961/ie7.png

Here's the CSS for that menu chunk:

```
    #mm #leftNav .navigation {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    float: left;
}

#mm #leftNav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}

#mm #leftNav .navigation li ul {
    display: none;
}

#mm #leftNav .navigation li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 11pt;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#mm #leftNav .navigation li {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.menu_item {
    background: #419185; 
}

.menu_item:hover {
    background: #48a093;
}

.currentcat {
    background-color: #4aa8a6;
}

.currentcat:hover {
    background: #4aa8a6;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="mm">
    <div id="leftNav">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a class="icon icon-base">Base</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a class="icon icon-devices">Devices</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a class="icon icon-management">Management</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a class="icon icon-iptools">IP Tools</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a class="icon icon-config">Configuration</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_item">
                <a class="icon icon-admin">Administration</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="subnav"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

top and bottom padding are not supported on inline elements (some browsers will render it, others won't)

Here's a good article on the problem:

http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/inline/

If you really need correct padding, you should change the menu items to "display:block" and "float:left"

Comment: Huh, I never knew that. Thanks for the article - I'll have a browse!

Comment: Gave it a go and it worked perfectly - it's the solution I was aiming for, as putting the padding/margin on the <a> itself caused me some trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Hehe, activa beat me to it.
Indeed, move your margin/padding to the A element, kinda like so:

## mm #leftNav .navigation li a {

```
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 11pt;
display:block;
float:left;
background: #419185;
margin-right: 4px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
```

}

## mm #leftNav .navigation li {

```
cursor: pointer;
```

}

.menu_item {

}

Comment: I believe this is actually how I had it originally, and there was a very good reason for me to change it, but I can't quite remember it! I think it gave me weird graphical errors in IE or somesuch. If I have time before the deadline then I'll have a fiddle, but it's just a cosmetic thing - no-one's especially bothered. :D